# Centering a search form using the bootstrap 3 on different screen sizes

Tags: forms, search, center, centering

Can any one help me centering a search bar in the center of the screen for different screen size, just like the googles search bar?

I have tried many ways but nothing worked.

```
<form class="form input-group" role="search">
    <div class="form-group center-block input-group-btn col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12col-lg-12">
        <div class="center-block" style="width: auto;">
            <div class="center-block ">  
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" style="width: auto;" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah, Have you tried this `<div align="center"></div>`? you can put the input inside it and its will work. or the whole form.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS will centre your content both vertically and horizontally, which I think is what you are wanting to achieve.

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
```